# jQuery Autocomplete via PHP error

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I'm trying to get an autocomplete working for a website I'm building for my company, but I can't seem to get the jQuery function to execute. The website is build on top of Wordpress.

The input line:

```
<strong>Customer: </strong> <input type='text' name='cust' id='cust'>
```

The autocomplete:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery('#cust').autocomplete({
    source : "Scripts/cust_search.php",
    minLength:1 
});
```

And cust_search.php:

```
<?
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET[ "term" ]));

$a_json = array ();
$a_json_row = array ();

if ($companies = $panther->get_results("SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name FROM Customer LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY Cust_Name ASC;")) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($companies)) {
    $a_json_row ["id"]=$panther->escape($row['Cust_ID']);
    $a_json_row ["value"]=$panther->escape($row['Cust_Name']);
    $a_json_row ["label"]=$panther->escape($row['Cust_Name']);

    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}
}

echo json_encode( $a_json );
?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem it seems to be your sql query.
You are missing WHERE statement

try

```
"SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name FROM Customer  WHERE **Cust_Name** LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY Cust_Name ASC;"
```

instead:

```
"SELECT Cust_ID, Cust_Name FROM Customer LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY Cust_Name ASC;"
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that, but I can't get to the point where the php file is the problem. I need to check on what's going on with my script request, because .autocomplete isn't being seen as a valid function in the console.

Comment: Please, post the error that is show up in your console.

Comment: Please, post the error that is show up in your console.
If autocomplete isn't a valid function might be your autocomplete integracion into jQuery as a plugin,
It seems that autocomplete it is not defined into jQuery.

try: this
1.- import your jquery lib
2.- import your autocomplete lib
3.- try with $('#element').autocomplete(options);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: in which part of your full file are you importing de jQuery file and your autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Jquery is being loaded by the header for the page, part of loading Wordpress. I thought the autocomplete function was part of the default library of jQuery, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: actually autocomplete function exist into jQuery UI only
[link](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)
You have to add jQuery UI library, I think